# Programatically add CC addresses to the webfom

Tags: webforms

Can anyone help we with the code which would add the CC to the webform? I need the CC feature, so my users can "Reply to All" when the communicate.

Thanks!
Anton.

Comment: I have tries the following, but it is not working:
`function mytheme_webform_mail_headers($variables) {
    $headers = array(
    'X-Mailer' => 'Drupal Webform (PHP/' . phpversion() . ')',
    );

    $headers['cc'] = 'email@example.com';

    return $headers;
}`

Comment: Is it ok to send email to multiple users? instead of CC?